# Need help getting child windows

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010, handle, spy++

I am working in vb with visual studio 2010.

The app AnyOrder is no longer supported and I am trying to make an app where our users can type in info and then have the info populate into AnyOrder (and also other sites - they have to populate a lot of redundant info) but I am having no luck at all getting the child windows of any order to populate once the data is in the VB window app.

I can get the parent window handle just fine but can't seem to get a child window handle to save my life. I can't even get the first level down and the blanks that I will need to populate are great grand-children of the parent window.

It won't let me post a screencap of the spy++ since I just signed up and don't have the 10 rep but here is a link to the capture.

[image]

Thank you in advance for any assistance that you can provide.

Comment: Please show the code that you are using to get your window handles

Comment: I am not sure what I did to fix it but I got it working and figured I'd put the code I cobbled together here in case someone else needs it. Maybe there is a better way to do this, but this at least gets the list of handles into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the answer somehow.

```
#Region "functions"
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Int32
Public Delegate Function EnumWindowProcess(ByVal Handle As IntPtr, ByVal Parameter As IntPtr) As Boolean
<DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Private Shared Function EnumChildWindows(ByVal WindowHandle As IntPtr, ByVal Callback As EnumWindowProcess, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function
Private Shared Function EnumWindow(ByVal Handle As IntPtr, ByVal Parameter As IntPtr) As Boolean
Dim ChildrenList As List(Of IntPtr) = CType(GCHandle.FromIntPtr(Parameter).Target, Global.System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Global.System.IntPtr))
ChildrenList = CType(GCHandle.FromIntPtr(Parameter).Target, Global.System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Global.System.IntPtr))
If ChildrenList Is Nothing Then Throw New Exception("GCHandle Target could not be cast as List(Of IntPtr)")
ChildrenList.Add(Handle)
Return True
End Function
Private Shared Function GetChildWindows(ByVal ParentHandle As IntPtr) As IntPtr()
Dim ListHandle As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(ChildrenList)
Try
    EnumChildWindows(ParentHandle, AddressOf EnumWindow, GCHandle.ToIntPtr(ListHandle))
Finally
    If ListHandle.IsAllocated Then ListHandle.Free()
End Try
Return ChildrenList.ToArray
End Function
#End Region

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
iParentHandle = FindWindow(vbNullString, AOParentName)
GetChildWindows(FindWindow(vbNullString, AOParentName))
Dim Childlist As String = String.Join(". ", ChildrenList)
MsgBox("list of child windows: " & Childlist)
End Sub
```