# Spy++ not getting individual handles - parts of form do not appear to have handles

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, automation, handle, spy++

I have the AnyOrder application open and when I open spy++ and use the finder tool I can identify the handles of most blanks but there are a couple parts of the GUI that don't seem to have individual handles. My rep isn't high enough to post a pic yet but if you look at the pic below you will see that the entire Payments box is highlighted even though the cross hair is on Paid1 (screen cap didn't get that). The Paid1, Date1, Paid2 and Date2 don't allow me to grab the handles individually, either with the spy++ cross hairs or by cycling through all handles and child handles for the application. So I'm not sure if there are even handles (seems unlikely but maybe I don't understand handles completely).

http://i25.photobucket.com/albums/c87/rogdor/screencap/spy2.png

I need to enter info into those fields but I am not sure how to get to them without a handle.

Code that I use to cycle through the child handles is in a different post below. It does grab and list all the handles listed for the app in spy++. It didn't seem relevant here.
[Need help getting child windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719893/need-help-getting-child-windows)

Comment: There is no law that says every screen element must be a window handle. Since you are trying to automate the application, you should be using automation interfaces. That's what they're for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm just starting out, so apologies if the question is basic or if I am missing something. Automation interfaces - I haven't messed with them at all yet and hadn't considered them. This application has no APIs at all either and we are trying to populate the data ideally without bringing the application window to the front. In looking at the automation interface help in VS 2010 it looks like I would need to move the mouse to the fields? Is that what you are recommending or am I missing something?

Comment: You don't say what programming language you are using. If you are using .NET, you can use `System.Windows.Automation` to programmatically modify controls in applications. If you are using C++, you can use `IUIAutomation`.

Comment: Sorry. Too little sleep = too little info it seems I am using .Net. I will give system.windows.automation a whirl. Thanks!

Comment: OK, no clue what I am doing wrong here but I can't seem to get this namespace to load or even list. I'm using .net vb 2010 and I can do imports system.windows but after that I don't have .automation in the list. I'm sure it is some silly newbie mistake. What am I missing?

Comment: The documentation says [Assembly:  UIAutomationClient (in UIAutomationClient.dll)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Yup I saw that. I confirmed that file is on my hard drive. It finds it in multiple locations but I assume the relevant one is C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0. So again, I am a beginner and I thought I should be doing an imports statement to use it but as I said. I can't do imports system.windows.automation like it says in that document. Am I supposed to access it another way or something?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion for automation Raymond.
Figured out the answer on adding the namespace. As I said, I am new so I needed this level of instruction at this this point. Putting it here in case someone comes across this thread and needs the answer.

In solution explorer, right click the solution name.
Choose "add reference" from the list
Scroll down to UIAutomationClient, select it and click OK (they aren't alphabetical by default so you may want to click the column header)
NOW you can add "Imports System.Windows.Automation"